# Visual Studio 2010/WinForm/Snap-To Lines/Control Visibility

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Every so often, I lose the pink and blue snap-to lines when editing a WinForm in VS2010. I have tried rebooting my workstation, closing unnecessary open applications, checking and unchecking the various options in Environment>General>Visual experience, but this still happens. It makes editing WinForms very difficult when you can't see the control you are dragging around and where you are dragging it to. I checked with The Googles and didn't locate a definitive answer. Anyone else have a solution for this?

Comment: You are the first to report this afaik.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report the issue.  They will need much better details than you gave here or they'll quickly close it as "not reproducible".  A minidump for example.

Comment: I may be the first here, but certainly others experience this as well.  Plenty of posts about this outside of SO but the only suggestions I've seen have do do with the Visual experience settings and those haven't done the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my workstation reimaged and reinstalled VS2010 + SP1, things seem to be working again.  I have not seen this problem for a couple days.